# Parse Server - Where do you store session token in single page application?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I have an Angular4 SPA + Parse Server. Currently, I'm implementing authentication with `Parse.User.logIn(...)` and `Parse.User.logOut(...)` directly on web page. The thing that I am worried about is storing session token received from `logIn()` method in Angular app. Whatever is stored on client side (even local storage or session storage) is prone to XSS attacks.

The only workaround I see is to implement custom login and logout methods in cloud code. On successful login cloud code could store session token in a cookie (secure, httpOnly) and would on every subsequent request parse token from cookie and set it in request as header "X-Parse-Session-Token", and then Parse Server logic would take over.

I guess this would work but I'm wondering how are you guys solving this problem. Where are you storing the token on web page?

Comment: This is an interesting issue that you raise here, I don't believe it was ever reported this way. The workaround you describe in Cloud Code is not necessary I believe. A solution would probably be to set the cookie server side and only in HTTPS serve it in the JS SDK. The we could use this cookie instead of the session token header. 

Also, I would not worry too much about those as if your application gets hacked through xss, you may have other worries than exfiled session tokens.

Comment: @flovilmart Probably HTTPS **and httpOnly**, otherwise it could still be exploited by XSS attack? But anyway, this cookie functionality would need to be added, right? As far I remember cloud code currently inspects only X-Parse-Session-Token header.

Comment: Yes it only uses this header in order use the cookie. Those are reasonable changes that I'm willing to consider in the SDK and server if you wish to implement them. I am not expert with XSS attacks to the point of offering a complete mitigation solution.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll see what I can achieve with my solution and maybe prepare a pull request later on.